# Can you please give feedback on my C++ Code?

Tags: c++, gcc

Can you please give feedback on my C++ code so I can get better at writing code? I want a code that is well written.

This Code uses the cstdio include for good performance and cstdint include because it has the int8_t data type to save memory. What this code does is if you type a number it will output something like I don't know how to describe:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    int8_t input {};
    printf("Welcome Type 1 or 2 or 3: ");
    scanf("%i", &input);

    switch(input)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("OK!");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("Yuo kown tsih is Cdeo");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Ediot Besh yor stoped");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("WhY dId YoU eVeN cHoOsE tHiS");
            break;
        case -9:
            printf("01001110 01001111 01010100 00100000 01001100 01000101 01000111 01001001 01010100");
            break;
        default:
            printf("idk what to output");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is really weird code....What does the third phrase mean? (Case 2)

Answer (score 5):

## Don't optimize prematurely

> This Code uses the cstdio include for good performance

If you write C++ code, it is better to use the C++ way of doing things. While `stdio` is generally slightly faster than `iostream`s, if printing to standard output is not the performance critical part of your program, you shouldn't switch to `printf()`, as you lose all of the benefits of `iostream`s, like type safety and interoperability with other C++ features.

Since you tagged the question C++20, you should know that [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) is even faster than `stdio` at formatting output, and combines the best of both worlds.

In the code you posted, you only output string literals, so no formatting is involved and likely all three methods will perform similarly.

## Type safety

I already mentioned that `stdio` is less type safe. And indeed you have an error: `scanf("%i", ...)` expects a pointer to an `int`, not an `int8_t`. This means you potentially overwrite the stack here. This problem would not have happened with `iostream`s, although `std::cin >> input` will likely not give the result you expect. When reading in an integer, just use `int`.

Again, this is likely premature and misguided optimization. A single `int8_t` will not be more efficient than an `int`, and in fact might be less efficient. Only if you store large amounts of values, such as in an array, will it make sense to use small integer types to save memory space and bandwidth.

## Don't forget to add newlines

You print strings without `\n` at the end. This might cause the output to not appear immediately (standard output is usually line-buffered), and the next print statement will print on the same line, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Good review for what is there, but I don't think I would have answered, since it looks like a troll is at work.

Comment: I was unsure whether to answer as well, but it does have value in case the OP is legitemately interested in a review or if another beginner programmer finds this post somehow.